# Wrong cursor movement win32api

Tags: python, winapi

I am trying to move my cursor with win32api. I need to move to the point mid_x and mid_y knowing my current cursor position(x,y).

```
x, y = win32api.GetCursorPos()
```

Then, I find how much should i move.

```
dx = int(mid_x -x)
dy= int(mid_y - y)
```

Finally, i move my cursor!

```
win32api.mouse_event(0x0001, dx,dy, 0, 0)
```

In the end, my mouse moves in a wrong direction. I read a c++ documentation and found that dx and dy should be a `mickey value`. What does that mean and how can i change it to pixels?

Comment: Use `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE` (0x8000) then you can just specify the absolute coordinates to move to. Note that `mouse_event` is deprecated, you should use `SendInput` instead (if this is available from python).

Comment: win32api.mouse_event(0x8000, dx, dy ,0 , 0)  mouse didn't move at all

Comment: You need to or it with the existing flag. Probably reading the docs wouldn't hurt.

Comment: ok. I figured it out

Answer (score 0):

```
//get the Screen resolution.
scalex = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CXSCREEN);
scaley = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CYSCREEN);

//get the scale(a screen has 65535*65535 mickey value)
scalex = 65535 / scalex;
scaley = 65535 / scaley;

win32api.mouse_event(0x8000 | 0x0001, dx* scalex, dy* scaley, 0, 0);
```